# Hibernate native query selecting entities with joined many-to-many association

Tags: java, hibernate, join, many-to-many, nativequery

I’m not used to ask for help but I’m really stuck for a few days. No way to find the same issue on Stackoverflow or Google...

I have two entities Event and Artist with a many-to-many relationship. The join table is EventArtists.

> Event <-- EventArtists --> Artist

**Artist**

```
@Entity
public class Artist {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long idArtist;
private String name;
private String description;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "artists")
private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>();
```

**Event**

```
@Entity
public class Event {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long idEvent;
private String name;
private String description;
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="EventArtists",
        joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="idEvent"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="idArtist")
)
private Set<Artist> artists = new HashSet<Artist>();
```

I’m trying to fetch an event and its associated artists using a native query.
According to the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-entity-associations-query), I’m using addEntity and addJoin.
Since the two entities are mapped to the same column names (id, name, description), I also use aliases.

Here is my request:

```
NativeQuery nativeQuery = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT {e.*}, {a.*} "+
      "FROM Event e "+
      "LEFT JOIN EventArtists ea ON e.idEvent = ea.idEvent "+
      "LEFT JOIN Artist a ON a.idArtist = ea.idArtist "+
      "WHERE e.idEvent = :id");
nativeQuery.addEntity("e", Event.class)
         .addJoin("a", "e.artists")
         .setParameter("id", 1);
nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

nativeQuery.getResultList() throws the following exception :

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "A.IDEVENT" not found

Indeed, Hibernate doesn’t generate correctly the request. It looks for columns "a.idEvent as idEvent1_2_0__, a.idArtist as idArtist2_2_0__", which are EventArtists's columns.

We get:

> SELECT
>           e.idEvent as idEvent1_1_0_,
>           e.description as descript2_1_0_,
>           e.name as name3_1_0_,
>           a.idEvent as idEvent1_2_0__,
>           a.idArtist as idArtist2_2_0__,
>           a.idArtist as idArtist1_0_1_,
>           a.description as descript2_0_1_,
>           a.name as name3_0_1_ 
>       FROM
>           Event e 
>       LEFT JOIN
>           EventArtists ea 
>               ON e.idEvent = ea.idEvent 
>       LEFT JOIN
>           Artist a 
>               ON a.idArtist = ea.idArtist 
>       WHERE
>           e.idEvent = ?

instead of

> SELECT
>           e.idEvent as idEvent1_1_0_,
>           e.description as descript2_1_0_,
>           e.name as name3_1_0_,
>           a.idArtist as idArtist1_0_1_,
>           a.description as descript2_0_1_,
>           a.name as name3_0_1_ 
>       FROM
>           Event e 
>       LEFT JOIN
>           EventArtists ea 
>               ON e.idEvent = ea.idEvent 
>       LEFT JOIN
>           Artist a 
>               ON a.idArtist = ea.idArtist 
>       WHERE
>           e.idEvent = ?

- Here is a complete TestCase:
  https://github.com/volvotrax/hibernate/
- The HQL query works perfectly but I need to use a native query since the where clause is much more complicated and relies on a database functionality.

> "FROM Event e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.artists WHERE e.idEvent = :id"

- Renaming column names to avoid using aliases is a solution but it’s not possible.
- I'm using Hibernate 5.2

Your assistance will be very much appreciated.
Thank you